# How to Create a Loop Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML + this JQuery.JS 
The Script works like this. When you Press the Add Button a Form will appear over the Table, when you press the hide button it will hide it When you press the Edit button any text that you will add in the form input cases will be added to a new TR that will be created with the Submit button.

What I want to do now is. On each TD line, I want my ADD/HIDE/Edit buttons to reappear but this time when I push Edit. I want to edit the new text that is in the new TR.
For Example, I have in first TR a, a, a, a, a I press Edit I put b, b, b, b, b, Submit it a new TR will be created with the bbbbb and when I push the Edit button again that is on the bbbbb tr. I want it to edit the bbbbb Line. I don't know how to explain it better than this. I can reach via skype if you guys want idk.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var valid = true,
            message = '';

        $('form input').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (!$this.val()) {
                var inputName = $this.attr('name');
                valid = false;
                message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            alert(message);
        } else {
            $('table').append('' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '');
            for(var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
                $('#btd' + x ).val('');
            }
            $('.buttons').attr('rowspan', $('tr').length);
        }
    });

    $(".hide").click(function () {
        $("form").hide();
    });
    $(".add").click(function () {
        $("form").show();
    });

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        $("form").show();
        $.each($(this).parent().parent().find('td'), function (key, val) {
            $("form input[type=text]").eq(key).val($(val).text());
        })
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {
        //$("form").show();
        //$("#btd1").val("Vlad");
        //$("#btd2").val("Andrei");
        //$("#btd3").val("vTask");
        //  $("#btd4").val("Ceva");
        //$("#btd5").val("Alceva");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title ></title >
  </head >
<body >
<form class="a" action="" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nume" id="btd1" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="prenume" id="btd2" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="email" id="btd3" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="btd4" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="parola" id="btd5" value="" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form >
<table border="2" >
    <tr >
        <td >Vlad</td >
        <td >Andrei</td >
        <td >vTask</td >
        <td >Ceva</td >
        <td >Alceva</td >
        <td class="buttons" style="vertical-align: top">
            <button class="add" >Add</button >
            <button class="hide" >Hide</button >
            <button class="edit" >Edit</button >
        </td >
    </tr >
</table >

</body >
</html >
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Added an edit to replace your local jquery script reference with the CDN.  Now the code snippet doesn't complain when you run it

Comment: ...and I have approved the edit, but it needs another approval from someone else

Comment: Cool.  Hopefully someone reviews it.  You mention that you want your Add/Hide/Edit buttons to 'reappear' but from what I can see they never actually disappear.    Maybe you should update your OP with a numbered list of steps detailing the expected behavior, or the current behavior vs expected?

Comment: I don't want them to disappear, they can remain visible on each new TR.

Comment: I just want the Edit button to edit the new column that he is on.

Comment: I start the table with a, a, a, a, a . When I push Edit the a, a, a, a, a will appear into the form. I edit it to b, b, b, b, b, and push submit. A new TR will be created under the start one with the b, b, b, b, b in it and when I push the edit button that is aside the b, b, b, b, b column I want the b, b, b, b, b text to appear into the form. Im really bad at puting this into words

Comment: On short I want the buttons to repeat but the Edit button to edit the column that he is on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fellow romanian you need something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var valid = true,
            message = '';

        $('form input').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (!$this.val()) {
                var inputName = $this.attr('name');
                valid = false;
                message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            alert(message);
        } else {
            $('table').append('' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td class="buttons" style="vertical-align: top"><button class="add" >Add</button><button class="hide" >Hide</button><button class="edit">Edit</button></td >'+
                '</tr>' +
                '');
            for(var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
                $('#btd' + x ).val('');
            }
        }
    });

    $("body").on('click','.hide',function () {
        $("form").hide();
    });
    $("body").on('click','.add',function () {
        $("form").show();
    });

    $("body").on('click','.edit',function () {
        $("form").show();
        $.each($(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(".buttons")'), function (key, val) {
            $("form input[type=text]").eq(key).val($(val).text());
        })
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {
        //$("form").show();
        //$("#btd1").val("Vlad");
        //$("#btd2").val("Andrei");
        //$("#btd3").val("vTask");
        //  $("#btd4").val("Ceva");
        //$("#btd5").val("Alceva");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title ></title >
  </head >
<body >
<form class="a" action="" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nume" id="btd1" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="prenume" id="btd2" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="email" id="btd3" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="btd4" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="parola" id="btd5" value="" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form >
<table border="2" >
    <tr >
        <td >Vlad</td >
        <td >Andrei</td >
        <td >vTask</td >
        <td >Ceva</td >
        <td >Alceva</td >
        <td class="buttons">
            <button class="add" >Add</button >
            <button class="hide" >Hide</button >
            <button class="edit" >Edit</button >
        </td >
    </tr >
</table >

</body >
</html >
```